# Linq2Sql - Converting Code - Visual Studio 2012 - Unit Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5, integration-testing

I have been trying to convert the code below. I have attempted it and I will post the attempt beneath the code below. I am confused when it comes to

**Code That I have to convert:**

---

```
[TestMethod]
        public void SRSTransactiondataCleanTest()
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new
               SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CorporateDWTest;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                str.Append(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned]");
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str.ToString(), sqlConn);
                DataTable dResults = new DataTable();
                DataTable dAudit = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dResults);

                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT [Table_Name],[Package_Name],[Execution_Start_Time],[Execution_End_Time],[Processing_Successful], Audit_Key," +
                    @"[Table_Initial_Row_Count],[Table_Final_Row_Count] FROM [SRS_Dim_Audit] WHERE Package_Name LIKE 'SAPSRSDataToStageClean'";

                da.Fill(dAudit);
                var r = dAudit.Rows[0][2].ToString();

                Assert.AreEqual(1, dAudit.Rows.Count);
                Assert.AreEqual("SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned", dAudit.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                Assert.AreEqual("SAPSRSDataToStageClean", dAudit.Rows[0][1].ToString());
                Assert.AreEqual(bool.TrueString, dAudit.Rows[0][4].ToString());
                Assert.IsTrue(int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][7].ToString()) > 10);
                Assert.IsTrue(dResults.Rows.Count > 50);
                Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][7].ToString()), dResults.Rows.Count);
                Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][5].ToString()), int.Parse(dResults.Rows[0][2].ToString()))
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
       }
```

---

**What I have so far:**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void SRSTransactiondataCleanTest()
        {
            using (var context = new CorporateDWTestEntities4())
            {
                var stageCleaned = context.SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned;
                var auditRecords = context.SRS_Dim_Audit.Where(s => s.Package_Name == "SAPSRSDataToStageClean");
                var auditRecord = auditRecords.FirstOrDefault();

                Assert.AreEqual(1, stageCleaned.Count());
                Assert.AreEqual(auditRecord.Table_Final_Row_Count, stageCleaned.Count());
                Assert.AreEqual(52, auditRecords.Count());
                Assert.AreEqual("SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned", auditRecord.Table_Name);
                Assert.AreEqual("SAPSRSDataToStageClean", auditRecord.Package_Name);
                Assert.AreEqual(true, auditRecord.Processing_Successful);
                Assert.IsTrue(auditRecord.Table_Final_Row_Count > 10);

            }
        }
```

---

I am fairly new at this code conversion stuff.. Am I on the right track? When I run this I recieve a message that states:

```
"Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected <1>. Actual <9461>."
```

When I change it to 9461, the entire test passes. Why is that? Am I using the wrong variable? I would just like to know if the code that I wrote is actually mirroring the code that I was to convert. I know with programming syntax must be meticulous. I was wondering if someone out there could review this and modify IF necessary.

**Ps. the line:**

```
  Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][5].ToString()), int.Parse(dResults.Rows[0][2].ToString()));
```

confused the hell out of me, What is that even asking of me?

Comment: Please note that these are *not* unit tests, they are integration tests.

Comment: @Daniel, the pedantry on display to argue that a user who has written a test method decorated as such according to the dictates of the unit-testing framework he is using is not in fact a unit-test is impressive.

Comment: @KirkWoll It's an important distinction, especially for people new to unit testing. I've worked with a lot of clients who didn't adequately understand the distinction and were down on the practice of unit testing because they had a massive suite of brittle, tightly-coupled integration tests that they were going crazy trying to maintain.

Comment: Daniel, it's not even remotely relevent to the discussion at hand.

Comment: I'd agree with Dan - For someone new to unit testing, there's a really good reason to understand the distinction between integration and unit testing, since the practice of understanding the scope and writing good UNIT tests will have a marked effect on design.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer. The same way people post comments about SQL injection vulnerabilities when someone asks a SQL-related question that has a vulnerability. Those comments aren't relevant to the question, but it's still useful information.

Comment: it was a mistake people. I understand the difference, I was just tagging quickly and recklessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first test should be

```
 Assert.AreEqual(1, auditRecords.Count());
```

rather than

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, stageCleaned.Count());
```

You also have a test

```
Assert.AreEqual(52, auditRecords.Count());
```

I can't see where you get 52 free. If this is supposed to be the equivalent of

```
Assert.IsTrue(dResults.Rows.Count > 50);
```

then it should be

```
Assert.IsTrue(stageCleaned.Count() > 50);
```

Not sure why you are confused by the line

```
 Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][5].ToString()), int.Parse(dResults.Rows[0][2].ToString()));
```

You must be very close as you have already worked out what all the other `dAudit.Rows[0][...]` values are,  so presumably you know that `int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][5].ToString())` represents `auditRecord.Audit_Key` (assuming this is defined as an int). Similarly `dResults.Rows[0][2]` will be the the third column of the first row from the SRS_Ticket_Transaction_Stage_Cleaned table.

So presumably this represents something like

```
var firstStageRecord = stageCleaned.First();
Assert.IsTrue(auditRecord.Audit_Key , firstStageRecord.xxx);
```

where xxx is the name of the third column.

There are a few other issues to point out.
If you have several calls to stageCleaned.Count(), it will issue a sql command each time is is called.

The original code was hard-coding the sqlConnection, whereas your new code is either using the default or picking up a connection from a configuration file, so you need to check to ensure you are talking to the correct database.